# "Meeting was spoiled due to some unavoidable circumstances". Is this line correct?

Tags: single-word-requests, syntactic-analysis

> Meeting was **spoiled** due to some unavoidable circumstances.

Is this line correct? I don't want to use the word ***spoil***. I want to mean that the meeting started, some discussions were made but due to some issues, the meeting stopped before completion. There was an intention to continue the meeting and to discuss on the remaining agenda but it was not possible. What should I write?

Comment: Is there an intent to continue the meeting at a later stage, or was the meeting abandoned?

Comment: _The meeting..._ and how about terminated

Comment: @Lawrence Yes there was an intention to continue the meeting and to discuss on the remaining agenda.

Comment: @user1942348 Please don't answer in comments. Please make the question itself contain all relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Meeting **ended abruptly** due to...

See [more examples](https://www.google.co.in/search?&q=%22Meeting%20ended%20abruptly%20due%20to%22) on Google.

***Abrupt*** -- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abrupt)

> (adjective) 1.a. characterized by or involving action or change without preparation or warning :  sudden and unexpected :
>
> (adverb) *"Ended the meeting abruptly"*

Answer (score 0):

The meeting was *adjourned*.

> **adjourned** *verb*
>   Break off (a meeting, legal case, or game) with the intention of resuming it later:
>   ‘the meeting was adjourned until December 4’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adjourn)